# angular + nginx + docker routing config issues when reloading

Tags: angular, docker, nginx, routes

I'm using angular with nginx as reverse proxy inside a docker container.

I'm having issues with the routing of the angular app, I can navigate through the different pages through the navbar just fine, but if I reload the page I get a 404 error(404 Not Found nginx/1.17.4). It also happens if I try to access any of the custom subpages directly. I tried looking up this issue, it seems like it's common.

I found that a common solution is to use the try_files option in nginx's config file, but it didn't work for me. When I make that change, the .js and .css files of the app never load.
This is my nginx config file:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name <server_name>;
    server_tokens off;
    location /.well-known/acme-challenge/ {
        root /var/www/certbot;
    }
    location / {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;   
    }
}
server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name <server_name>;
    server_tokens off;
    ssl_certificate /path/to/pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /path/to/pem;
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf;
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem;
    location / {
        proxy_pass  http://front_server/;
        proxy_set_header    Host                $http_host;
        proxy_set_header    X-Real-IP           $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-For     $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        root /usr/share/nginx/html;
        index index.html index.htm;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html =404;
    }
    location /api/ {
        proxy_pass <proxy_endpoint>;
        proxy_set_header    Host                $http_host;
        proxy_set_header    X-Real-IP           $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-For     $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }
}
```

I don't really have a lot of experience with the technologies involved. Do you guys see any possible problem with this config file? I have tried all the different permutations I've found online with no luck but I'm willing to try everything again at this point. Thank you!

Comment: could you please open devtools/network tab and show which exact url your js is requested from, and the response it gets?

Answer (score 0):

I suppose it is SPA and angular frontend is running on on `front_server` container, then try this one:

```
location / {
    proxy_pass  http://front_server/;
    proxy_set_header    Host                $http_host;
    proxy_set_header    X-Real-IP           $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-For     $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
}
```

Comment: this is the original config we had which doesn't allow for refreshing the custom subpages nor the direct accessing (as in page.com/subpage1, which works fine while routing through the navbar). I'm trying to understand how to use try_files to make that work.

Comment: Is your angular app currently hosted on front_server ? Is front_server based on Nginx ?